# after I added jQueryMobile, why <a> open the target page in the current page?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have worked in a project of mine only with jQuery, after I added the jQueryMobile and Migrate all `<a>` elements to show the target page on the current page, the question arose: How do I make it work as before (relocate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code looks like:

```
<a href="some Jesus website link">Jesus is Lord</a>
```

Your code should looke like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="some Jesus website link">Jesus is Lord</a>
```

If it doesn't work, show me your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Cordova & jQueryMobile, your app is converted to a single-page app. All links to internal pages should open in the same browser window automatically replacing the current page. Your app should not have any popup page.

Read on [this page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/intro/) under the title **Ajax Navigation & Transitions** how jQueryMobile intercepts you links events and convert them to Ajax requests.

To create a popup in jQueryMobile apps, use the `Dialog Widget`.

For links to external pages in Cordova apps, use the `InAppBrowser` plugin.

Comment: Okay, I understood thank you.
Do you have any idea how to make swipe left/right listener in jQuery not in jQueryMobile..?

Comment: this is why i used jQueryMobile by the way

Comment: You need to use the `swipe` events. Check [this page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-page/) and [this page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-list/) for demos.